# ActiveAdmin form within a custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Consider the following ActiveAdmin page:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Import" do
    content do
        form :action => some_path, :method => :post do |f|
            f.input :name => :table, :collection => { "Display" => "id" }
        end
    end
end
```

Using this code anywhere within an ActiveAdmin resource works as you would expect, using FormBuilder to create a Formtastic form. When using AA's register_page method, however, and placing a form in the `content` section, it doesn't seem to work as hoped. Am I missing something or could this be something that's been overlooked? I might create the form in a partial rather than use AA's DSL, but it would be nicer to keep it within the AA resource.

Anyone got a clue why it won't play nice?

Comment: Please be a little more specific when you say, 'won't play nice.'  What did you expect to see?  What did you actually see?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I noticed that too in the past. My problem was that it seemed Cancan wouldn't work properly anymore when I would go to one of my own custom page...disregarding the admin abilities I had set.

If you look at your logs though, you'll notice that Custom pages render the following:

```
app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb
```

whereas a "normal" resource page renders the following

```
app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb
```

So I think any helpers/methods tied to ActiveAdmin and ActiveRecord models won't work in custom page. Seems like they only work if it renders templates under `/resource/*`

Just like you said..I went around that problem by creating my own partials !

Comment: Hopefully it's something queued for resolution in future updates of AA, but its not justification for my spending any time on given that there is a clear workaround.